# Definition of locally convex topological vector space but it has cosets?!

Tags: functional-analysis

In my course the following definition is provided

> Defn (Locally convex topological vector space) A topology
> $\tau_{\mathscr{P}}$ induced by a family of separating norms
> $\mathscr{P}$ is generated by $$ \beta=\{x+B: x \in X, B \in
>  \dot{\beta}\} $$ where $\dot{\beta}$ consists of finite interesctions
> of $$ V(p, n)=\left\{x \in X: p(x)<\frac{1}{n}\right\}, \quad p \in
>  \mathscr{P}, n \in \mathbb{N} . $$ We call $\left(X,
>  \tau_{\mathscr{P}}\right)$ a locally convex topological vector space.

My issue with this is that the generating set is a set of cosets. Then what we generate is again going to be made out of cosets and hence  $\tau$ can not be a topology of $X$.

**Context:** Here $X$ is a vector space.

**Answering if this is a duplicate:** I have searched on this website and on wikipedia, however, the definitions they seem to use are different and do not deal with cosets.

**Question:** Could someone explain to me how $\tau$ is a topology on the vector space/ clarify what is going on here?

Comment: Any family of subsets can generate a topology.

Comment: @MW yes but this is not what the definition says. We have a family of cosets. A coset is not a subset. Perhaps the definition is wrong?

Comment: 1. A coset is indeed a subset.  What definition were you using that said it isn’t? 2.  I would probably not use the word “coset” here, I would call it a translate - but maybe some people call them cosets.  Usually I think of a coset as a translate of a subgroup, ideal, or subspace, rather than an arbitrary translated set.

Comment: Hi, I assume this is my bad. I thought of cosets as algebraic objects but I think you are indeed correct. Feel free to post this an answer.

Comment: Understandable mistake, we do often “forget” the fact that a coset is a set and treat it like some kind of primitive object in a quotient space.  However, unless some source is using that term I would probably not even call these sets cosets in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, any family $\mathcal F\subseteq \mathcal P(X)$ of subsets (including, in this case, a family of translates of some other family) generates a topology on $X$, namely, the set of arbitrary unions of finite intersections of members of $\mathcal F$. $\mathcal F$ is typically called a “sub base” for the topology, and the set of finite intersections of members of $\mathcal F$ then becomes a base for this same topology.